# python user permissions

Tags: python

I have a question related to user permissions in python. I have a project that uses the file system to store information about specific tasks. Of course this can be edited/deleted if user wants to. Now say a user starts the program using `sudo sh start.sh`. He then does some operations and data is stored. Now if anyone else or even the same user will start the program without `sudo` rights when trying to delete/modify those file a permission denied `OSError` is raised. Now this seems logical but my question is:

1. Does python offer any way to choose the permissions when writing/creating a file/folder? More precisely can you create files that will be accessible to all users from sudo ?
2. Does python offer any way to request a users permission when starting the program/ during program execution?

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need [`os.fchown()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fchown).

I don't know what you mean by your second question - do you want to ask for a root password and use it to gain access to a file that the normal user wouldn't have access to?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean with my second question. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm afraid that Python doesn't have a way of elevating its own privileges that way.